# Powershell and CMD can't find any builtin commands

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh, cmd, path

I'm unable to use any common commands in windows cmd or powershell. For every command I get this error:

```
ssh: The term 'ssh' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
```

Or:

```
ipconfig: The term 'ipconfig' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
```

The ssh.exe is present though, so it may be an issue with wrong paths. I checked system variables and everything seems fine. What could be the issue here?

Comment: That sounds for me more like an issue for [https://superuser.com](https://superuser.com) than for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the environment variables such as `%PATH%` and `%COMSPEC%`. Most likely, there is a problem with `%PATH%` and it is missing some default directories that it usually contains.

Also try running [`sfc /scannow`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e).

AFAIK, `%PATH%` by default includes these directories:

- C:\Windows;
- C:\Windows\System32;
- C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
- C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

But this can change from system to system and perhaps Windows versions. Software you install on Windows may change `%PATH%` and add new directories into it.

Comment: Thanks, the directories were somehow missing from PATH.